# Maximal elements in a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove that if there are two maximal elements in a partially ordered set, then these maximal elements are not comparable.

I understand that I should show that if there are two maximal elements in a set, then they must be equal or not compareable. How should I write it down exactly?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $m$ and $n$ are two maximal elements that are comparable then $m\leq n\wedge n\leq m$ leading to $m=n$. So if they are comparable then they cannot be distinct.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\leq$ be a partial order on the set $A$, and let $a,b\in A$ be two maximal elements such that $a\neq b$. Now assume for contradiction that $a$ and $b$ are comparable, this means that either $a\leq b$ or $b\leq a$. The former contradicts the maximality of $a$, while the latter contradicts the maximality of $b$ thus $a$ and $b$ are not comparable.